# Converting column data into row in pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Hi When i went for an interview they asked me this  question.

```
    Create table course(Name CHAR(10));

    insert into course values ('Java');
    insert into course values ('Oracle');
    insert into course values ('Python');
    insert into course values ('C');
    insert into course values ('C++');

     o/p:
        Java Oracle python c c++
```

Thanks in advance,
Sandhya.

Comment: Hello sandhya, here SO users like you try to search by your own before asking us. Please also read this page to improve your question : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume that `NAME` column's datatype should have been `VARCHAR2`, not `CHAR`.

Anyway, another option (similar to Tejash's `LISTAGG`) which uses `XMLAGG` and is safer if the result is larger than 4000 characters.

```
SQL> SELECT RTRIM (
  2            XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (e, name || ' ') ORDER BY null).EXTRACT (
  3               '//text()'),
  4            ',')
  5            result
  6  FROM course;

RESULT
------------------------------------------------------------
Java       Oracle     Python     C          C++

SQL>
```

---

Or, as you tagged the question with PL/SQL tag, then an anonymous PL/SQL block might look like this:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> declare
  2    l_result varchar2(100);
  3  begin
  4    for cur_r in (select name from course) loop
  5      l_result := l_result ||' '|| cur_r.name;
  6    end loop;
  7
  8    dbms_output.put_line(trim(l_result));
  9  end;
 10  /
Java       Oracle     Python     C          C++

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

Or - similarly - a function:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_course
  2    return varchar2
  3  is
  4    l_result varchar2(100);
  5  begin
  6    for cur_r in (select name from course) loop
  7      l_result := l_result ||' '|| cur_r.name;
  8    end loop;
  9
 10    return trim(l_result);
 11  end;
 12  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_course from dual;

F_COURSE
--------------------------------------------------------------
Java       Oracle     Python     C          C++

SQL>
```

---

Or, a procedure with an `OUT` parameter:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_course (par_result out varchar2)
  2  is
  3    l_result varchar2(100);
  4  begin
  5    for cur_r in (select name from course) loop
  6      l_result := l_result ||' '|| cur_r.name;
  7    end loop;
  8
  9    par_result := trim(l_result);
 10  end;
 11  /

Procedure created.

SQL> declare
  2    l_out varchar2(100);
  3  begin
  4    p_course(l_out);
  5    dbms_output.put_line(l_out);
  6  end;
  7  /
Java       Oracle     Python     C          C++

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

As you can see, quite a few options; use the one that most suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an aggregate function - `LISTAGG` as following:

> ```
> SQL> SELECT
>   2      LISTAGG(TRIM(NAME), ' ') WITHIN GROUP(
>   3          ORDER BY
>   4              NULL
>   5      ) AS RESULT
>   6  FROM
>   7      COURSE;
>
> RESULT
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> C C++ Java Oracle Python
>
> SQL>
> ```

Cheers!!